# Delimit various description in bulk in a column

Tags: excel, csv

I have a bulk various description in a column and each cell consists of 3 sentences. How can I delimit the first sentence to the other 2 sentences without delimiting the 3rd sentence on a seperate column (3rd column)? There should be only two columns 1st column for 1st sentence and 2nd column for the other two sentences.

Comment: Put the pipe | on "Others", right?

Comment: Thanks! Will try that.

Comment: @pnuts It works. But there is a need to do =CONCATENATE(A1,".") to bring back the period on the 1st sentence on 1st column